# How to design a content model for a page with multiple sections in Headless CMS?

Tags: headless-cms, content-model

I have been looking into headless cms concepts and would like to design a page like below?

[image]

In an headless cms, we can create individual input pages with the respective content model, "main page" will have one and "company" will have one.
[image]

We cannot create an input page by combining these two input pages, as the page can have any number of company object, so i dont think we can combine these two input pages as one? correct me if its wrong.

And, how we can combine the "company" data with "main page" so that we can get the full page? how do we create this relationship in the content model? Please advise. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Headless CMSes use the structured content approach. It's all about breaking things into pieces(blocks as some call it). In your example the "Page" would be it's own content type. The page would have a field for title, image and a special field (popularly called a reference field) for holding the content sections (the blocks). Then you have other content types like "Company" that you can use to create Company 1, Company 2... The magic is in the reference field, it's how you link all the content types to each other.